# What are the most used econometric methods in economics?

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, applied-econometrics

As the title says, I would like to know what methods are most often used in empirical economics. For example, are IVs used more than DiD?

I would prefer to see some survey of different methods that would show how many papers used it, or If there is no ranking even a list of most used method would be fine.

Comment: I would say that the market share of OLS is still about 50%, but it is a subjective estimate based on my readings.

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be useful. Different branches of economics use different models. I wonder if aggregating over the different branches makes much sense. Though it may depends on your intentions.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am just interested to know what models people use, I don't need it for some project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regression discontinuity, IV, diff-in-diff, fixed effects, synthetic control, and MLE, and GMM are the major methods.

Fixed Effects example - [Zou (2021)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20181346)

Fixed Effects and IV example - [Benzell and Cooke (2021)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.20180521)

Diff-in-diff example - [Gu, Jiang, Zhang, and Zou (2021)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.20190024)

Regression discontinuity (fuzzy also) - [Ost, Pan and Webber (2018)](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/ucpjlabec/doi_3a10.1086_2f696204.htm)

Regression Kink discontinuity - [Bana, Dedard, and Rossin-Slater (2020)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/pam.22242)

MLE example - [Farber (2008)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.98.3.1069)

Synthetic control - [Andersson (2019)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/pol.20170144)

GMM has a *lot* of applications, one example is production functions - [Ackerberg, Caves, and Frazer (2015)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.3982/ECTA13408)

Comment: Perhaps MLE and GMM are better understood an estmation frameworks rather than as methods.

Answer (score -1):

according to me that would be the **Spatial econometrics model**
Why?
The spatial model uses information gathered from different data sets to create models for use in business. The data either results in dependent data pieces or correlated data taken from a larger population of information. Therefore other models are under this one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).